# Setting column-width not working

Tags: css

So I have a table inside a div

```
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="some-table"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have

```
.table-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.some-table {
  column-width: 50px;
```

}

this doesn't seem to set the width of the columns. I also tried doing the same with the td elements, the only effect seems to be to increase the width of the columns if the original width was lower than 50px.

How do I set the column width to be something I want?

Comment: On which browser you are testing? if it is chrome or firefox, add also vendor prefixes. and the correct way of closing `table` tag is `<table></table>`.

Comment: Can you please post code that is more complete?

Comment: First of all, there are no columns in your table element. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it's difficult for me to post more complete code because I'm using data tables.js, which adds a bunch of extra stuff

Comment: css is crap 
<td style="width:200px;"> 
is giving me a column of 250px

Answer (score 2):

You should know that the `column-width` and `column-count` properties (and most other column-* properties) don't apply to tables, as stated in the [Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-width)

> **Name:   column-width**
>
> *Applies to:*     non-replaced block-level elements (**except table elements**), table cells, and inline-block elements

Comment: +1 nice. this info is not available in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width) :/

Comment: ohhh this is interesting - so how would I set column width? What I really have is tables of different width, I'm setting them to 100% width and then trying to control the column width to be something

Comment: @praks5432 Have a look at `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It is saying it is applicable also for table elements. right?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's browser issue, please try this:

```
.some-table {
    column-width:50px;
    -moz-column-width:50px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-width:50px; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```